# I trying open documentation on browser using swagger 3. But i can't

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I believe that i did the correct configurations, but i can't access the API documentation on browser:
I added dependency in pom.xml

- pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In application archive I added annotation for swagger 3:

- Application

```
package dio.myfirstapi;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My first API", version = "1", description = "API developed using Spring and Swagger"))
public class MyFirstApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyFirstApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And in Controller I added @Operation to inform descriptions...

- Controller

```
package dio.myfirstapi.controller;

import dio.myfirstapi.model.User;
import dio.myfirstapi.repository.UserRepository;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", produces = {"application/json"})
@Tag(name = "My first API")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping()
    @Operation(summary = "List Users", description = "List all users.")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    @Operation(summary = "User Details", description = "Receive username and return information about this user.")
    public User getOne(@PathVariable("username") String username){
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @Operation(summary = "Remove User", description = "Receive ID and remove user with this ID.")
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Operation(summary = "Receive user and save informations", description = "Cria um novo usuário com as informações fornecidas.")
    public void postUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

When I trying open documentation in browser:
[I can't open documentation in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN63r.png)

Comment: The docs on the library you added states you are using the wrong dependency? https://springdoc.org/#getting-started